# How to get the regression output in an Excel table in r?

Tags: r, regression

I am running many regressions and I want to have each group of them in an Excel file.

For example, this is a group of regressions that I want to have them in one table:

I used stargazer: they appear all in a perfect way together like in the attached picture but when I copy them, they are all put in one cell.

```
stargazer( dejure, defacto, JI, type="text", out="reg_EPI_JI_70.txt")
```

[image]

Here is the picture of how my data looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhmS5.png)

Comment: Here is the example of a group of regressions I wasn't able to post it in the questions: 
dejure <- lm(raw_EPI ~ dejure_index, data = reg_EPI_vars)
defacto <- lm(raw_EPI ~   defacto_index , data = reg_EPI_vars)
JI <-  lm(raw_EPI ~  dejure_index + defacto_index , data = reg_EPI_vars)

Comment: Could you provide `dput()` or `subset()` of your data?

Comment: I attached a picture of how my data looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
stargazer(dejure, defacto, JI, type = "html", out = "reg_EPI_JI_70.htm")
```

---

I found that `stargazer` is used for HTML. It works perfectly.